# how to step by step debug in mongodb's map/reduce

Tags: debugging, mongodb

Is there any way to **step by step** debug in MongoDB's map/reduce javascript?

It seems that we only can use `print()` to write some data to the log file. --> [mongodb: how to debug map/reduce on mongodb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527126/mongodb-how-to-debug-map-reduce-on-mongodb-shell)

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458382/how-can-you-debug-stored-javascript-functions-in-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following page which provides details on how to debug both the map and reduce steps in MongoDB MapReduce:[Troubleshooting MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Troubleshooting+MapReduce)

Comment: Feel free to leave comments on this page as well if there is anything that is unclear or that you think could be improved on this page. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you can attach a debugger to the Javascript engine mongo shell or set breakpoints by other means. My advice would be to write to log any information you may need to evaluate and examine there.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at this simple online MongoDB MapReduce debugger which allows to get aggregation results on sample data as well as perform step-by-step debugging of Map / Reduce / Finalize functions right in your browser dev environment (e.g. in Chrome DevTool).

http://targetprocess.github.io/mongo-mapreduce-debug-online/

Comment: You posted this same exact answer to a different question. Once again, link-only answers are discouraged. Please read ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)