# How to debug MongoDB JavaScript with V8 debugger

Tags: javascript, mongodb, debugging, v8

MongoDB [since 2.4](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/46419580374/mongodb-2-4-javascript-changes) [has V8](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407) as its JavaScript engine. As [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) contributor I wonder could it be possible to use the same V8 remote debugger to debug (with break-points, variable inspections etc) JavaScript running on Mongo instance.

Code example

```
rsconfig = rs.config()
printjson(rsconfig)
rsconfig.members[0].priority = 10
rs.reconfig(rsconfig)
```

So instead of `printjson` it would be better to have take a look into variables values, to get better insight of MongoDB

I started my search with Stackoverflow. MongoDB site has just a few pages at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Older questions (not V8 aware)

- [How can you debug stored javascript functions in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458382/how-can-you-debug-stored-javascript-functions-in-mongodb)
- [how to step by step debug in mongodb's map/reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360499/how-to-step-by-step-debug-in-mongodbs-map-reduce)

From Google group [Can I debug a mongo script?](http://www.marshut.com/itthzr/can-i-debug-a-mongo-script.html) -> answer is just No

Comment: Not to sure that there is ( or will be that level of exposure ) in JavasScript ( server side ) debugging. Kind of not a simple thing considering this is an instance interpreter. Also noting that the momentum is more focused towards the aggregation framework with native C++ implementation. So is there an actual use case for this? Or what type of complex JavaScript operations do you actually need to run? This is screaming **too broad** at me without further explanation, but I do encourage you to explain further if you believe you have a case.

Comment: Frakly I am coming from tools side. If it is possibly and take no much time, then we would plan to implement such support. (yes, My script were quite simple to give as example.)

Comment: What script? I see nothing. Possibly you should add something but unless there is actually a definitive answer to this ( which frankly I do not see ) then I cannot see how this question remain "on-topic" for this site.

Answer (score -1):

May not be exact answer for this question, but if somebody wants to write script and test it , just for manipulating mongo data.
You can always use nodejs with mongodb connector. And debug your js code using node-debugger.